# amending the x-axis of a histogram created with the df.hist function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am using the df.hist function and am looping through variables to create histogram plots.

I would like to create plots where the x-axis values are directly below the bars.

As one example, I have attached the following plot.

Here, I **don't** want '1.5','2.5' or '3.5' to be **displayed on the x-axis** and for the numbers '1','2' and '3' to be **aligned to the centre** of the bars.

I would be so grateful for a helping hand!

[image]

```
listedvariables = ['distance','duration','age','gender-quantised','hours_of_sleep','frequency_of_alarm_usage','sleepiness_bed','sleepiness_waking','sleep_quality','nap_duration_mins','frequency_of_naps','normal_time_of_wakeup','number_of_times_wakeup_during_night','time_spent_awake_during_night_mins','time_of_going_to_sleep','time_to_fall_asleep_mins','sleep_onset_time','sleep_period_length_mins','total_sleep_duration_mins','time_in_bed_mins','sleep_efficiency','sleep_bout_length_mins','mid_point_of_sleep','takes_naps_yes/no','sleepiness_resolution_index','highest_education_level_acheived','hours_exercise_per_week_in_last_6_months','drink_alcohol_yes/no','drink_caffeine_yes/no','hours_exercise_per_week','hours_of_phone_use_per_week','video_game_phone/tablet_hours_per_week','video_game_all_devices_hours_per_week']
for i in range(0,len(listedvariables)): 
    fig = newerdf[[listedvariables[i]]].hist(figsize=(30,20))
    [x.title.set_size(40) for x in fig.ravel()]
    [x.tick_params(axis='x',labelsize=40) for x in fig.ravel()]
    [x.tick_params(axis='y',labelsize=40) for x in fig.ravel()]
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the x-values are discrete, a histogram is not the right tool here. Instead, it seems like you want to create a bar plot. So try replacing `df.hist()` with [`df.plot.bar()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - when I replace df.hist() with what you suggested 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'ravel' :( Might you know how I can overcome this?

Comment: You can set the title and labelsizes by calling those methods directly on the axes object returned by `df.plot.bar()`. There should be no need for the `for x ...` loops in this case. However, you may of course want to keep the histogram approach for any variables that may indeed have continuous distributions.

Comment: Thanks so much for this suggestion - but somehow it still appears not normal - I am creating a new thread on this :)